# How to sync model watched by ngRepeat when the repeated DOMs are modified externally?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two lists which are rendered by my directive. The requirement is that user can move an item from one list to another. I have a simplified implementation of this below:-

http://jsfiddle.net/yK7Lt/

The above shows a demo of how it should behave. Notice in this I manipulate the model and the DOM auto-syncs with it.

However, the problem is I am using [jquery-ui-sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) plugin. So, the user can drag and drop the item from one list to another. Since jQuery is unaware of AngularJs so it modified the DOM. Now in my directive I have placed the code to sync the underlying model with the changed DOM.

The below jsfiddle code is a simplified version of my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Xuz2/1/

The relevant code snippet is:-

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var li = $('#left li').first().detach();
    $('#right').prepend(li);
    console.log('moved top DOM to right list');

    angular.element('#left').scope().$apply(function () {
        // The moment this code runs, the DOM related to i is
        // marked with $$NG_REMOVED, and is removed from page.
        // Also somehow the DOM related to item D too is removed.

        i = itemsl.shift(); // i is global variable.
    });
    angular.element('#right').scope().$apply(function () {
        itemsr.unshift(i);
        console.log('synced data with DOM');
    });
});
```

The problem I am facing with my implementation is that the right list empties out as soon as I sync my left list model.

- What is wrong with my implementation?
- Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is you are manipulating DOM with both Angular and jQuery... if you remove this piece of code

```
var li = $('#left li').first().detach();
$('#right').prepend(li);
```

it is working as expected

btw. I suggest trying angular-UI instead of jQueryUI

edit: OR you can try to refactor your code to something like this

```
var itemsl, itemsr, i, move;

function Model(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function Ctrl($scope) {
    itemsl = $scope.itemsl = [new Model('A'), new Model('B'), new Model('C')];
    itemsr = $scope.itemsr = [new Model('D')];
    move = function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            i = itemsl.slice(0,1);
            itemsl.splice(0,1);
            itemsr.unshift(i[0]);
            i = null;
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        console.log('moved top DOM to right list');
        move();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well actually the part which does the DOM manipulation is a rough estimate of what jQuery-UI does to my DOM.

Comment: Anyway your suggestion to use Angular-UI helped. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable is the thing I needed. Don't know why I did not google this before. Thanks.